# Splitting a noisy X-Shaped cluster into 2 "linear" clusters

Tags: image-processing, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis

Context:
I am currently working on an image-processing problem where I need to identify lines from a binary-noisy image. The Noise comes from the measurement and the signal processing round which extract the position of the transitions in our devices & cannot be further reduced.

"Clusters" are generated using a linkage algorithm (all points touching, or within a specified distance are grouped in a single cluster [In the given example, the criteria was a maximum hole size of one pixel between 2 transition points]).  I then compute a Hough Transform for each of these clusters, extracting the most likely angle and distance from origin of the best line.  I also extract the incertainty on both these variables (usually a few degres when the cluster is not a potato and has more than a few points).  Using these informations, I am able to reconstruct the lines quite efficiently (knowing that all adjacent transitions are always parallel when the our device has no defects). but here comes my problem:

Problem:
Because of device&design-specific impurities, some transitions will cross!  This means some of the clusters become X-shaped and my Hough transform no longer gives the proper angle nor incertainty for this cluster.  Also, because my recombination algorithm eliminates clusters when they are part of a transition, this means that some transitions become cut.

Solution:
I am looking for a way to split an X-shaped cluster into 2 "linear" clusters, each of which I could then apply the Hough transform on and perform my line-detection algorithm (which works very well when a dot has no impurity by the way!)

[image: Example of an X-shaped cluster in a small diagram]

Here are the Y-X coordinates of the X-shaped cluster featured in red in my example image (I know it's uncommon to have y-x coord. but it works best when working with matrix-like images):

239 240 240 241 241 242 242 243 243 244 244 245 245 246 246 247 247 248 248 249 249 250 250 251 252 252 252 252 253 253 253 252 252 253 253 253 253 254 254 253 254 255 255 251 251 253 256 254 255 255 257 257 250 251 251 258 255 255 257 258 259 259 250 250 251 251 260 256 260 261 261 249 249 250 251 251 262 257 262 263 263 249 249 264 264 256 265 265 265 248 249 266 266 267 267 268 268

658 658 659 658 659 660 661 656 657 658 657 659 660 657 658 660 661 658 659 662 663 661 662 663 659 660 663 664 661 662 665 657 658 657 658 659 660 663 664 666 667 665 666 655 656 656 664 668 668 669 666 667 653 653 654 666 670 671 671 667 667 668 651 652 651 652 668 672 669 669 670 649 650 650 649 650 670 674 671 668 669 647 648 668 669 675 667 668 669 646 646 666 667 669 670 668 669

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try something based on the idea of the RANSAC algorithm.

- Sample a few points from the X-shaped cluster, fit them by a line, and check how many points in the cluster are very close to that line.
- If the points you sampled come from two different branches of the X, the line fit will not match any of the branches of the X, so only few points will be very close to that line fit. In this case, discard and try sampling a few points again.
- If the points you sampled come the same branch of the X, almost all points on that branch should be very close to the line fit.
- If the number of points close to the line-fit is high, you can  say that all these points belong to one subcluster and compute your Hough transform on these points
- The rest of the points can be used to compute the other angle (or you can also sample points from the remaining points, fit a line to them and take all points that match that line)